# D3 - How to set start of "x" coordinate "rect" value to matching time/date on "x" axis

Tags: d3.js

I have created a D3 chart where I would like the "x" coordinate (rect) to be set via the "start_time" property of my data. The "x" axis scale is set to the last six hours. The "start_time" is within the six hour range so I am trying to get my data to match up to the time range on the x axis. (currently "start_time" is 5:30am and I would like my rectangle to start at 5:30am on the x axis). My code is below, thanks!

I'm using moment.js to create the time range so it's possible that something is wrong there as far as the two data properties talking to each other.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dtepdc/bmry9f04/4/

```
const data = [
{
    "start_time": "2019-01-15T05:30:40",
    "end_time": "2019-01-15T04:32:25",
    "elapsed_time": 89,
    "mynum":"CO12345"
}
  ];

const svgWidth = 700, svgHeight = 300;

const svg = d3.select('svg')
 .attr("width", svgWidth)
 .attr("height", svgHeight);

const start = moment().format('LLL');
const end = moment().subtract(12, 'hours').format('LLL');
const dataFormat = moment(data[0].start_time).format('LLL');

console.log('start: ', dataFormat)

const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
.domain([new Date(start), new Date(end)])
.range([0, svgWidth]);

const x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
.scale(xScale);

 svg.append("rect")
 .attr("width", "100%")
 .attr("height", "86%")
 .attr("fill", "#000");

svg.append("rect")
 .attr('x', function(d) { return d ; })
 .attr("y", 120)
 .attr("width", data[0].elapsed_time)
 .attr("height", 40)
 .attr("fill", "green");

svg.selectAll("text")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("text")
 .text(function(d) {
     return d.mynum;
 })
 .attr("x", 120)
 .attr("y", 148)
 .attr("width", data[0].elapsed_time)
 .attr("height", 50)
 .attr("font-size", 14)
 .attr("fill", "#fff");

const xAxisTranslate = svgHeight - 40;

svg.append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(50, " + xAxisTranslate  +")")
 .call(x_axis)
 .selectAll("text")
```

Comment: if you don't rewrite your code to use the margins correct you will almost never get the rect alligned. Look for an example from Mike for a line chart, d3v4 d3v5, You need to call the xScale to transform the start time to a pixel value

Answer (score -1):

I'm no d3 hero but the way I do it is to create my time scale instance and then use that to translate a date to a number.

```
x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, axisWidth]);
var xPos = x(moment(d.positionDate, "MM/D/YYYY h:mm a"));
```

So in your case it would be something like:

```
svg.append("rect")
 .attr('x', function(d) { 
    return moment(d.start_time, "MM/D/YYYY h:mm a") // not correct formatting
   })
 .attr("y", 120)
 .attr("width", data[0].elapsed_time)
 .attr("height", 40)
 .attr("fill", "green");
```

You should look up the `moment` formatting flags for your ""2019-01-15T05:30:40" data